# l am trying to store string values in an ArrayList and then print them to a file but my code is showing some errors of cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist

l am trying to store string values in an ArrayList and then print them to a file but my code is showing some errors of cannot find symbol. Where have l gone wrong. The following is my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arrays{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\java code\\Arrays.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        ArrayList<String> header = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("NAME","REGNUM","ACADEMICYEAR","PROGRAMME","COURSECODE","ASS1","ASS2","ASS3","TEST1","AGGREGATEDMARK","COURSEWORK","GRADE","RESULT"));

        pw.print(header);
        pw.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: And the OP called their class `Arrays` ...

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays` class name is having conflict. `Arrays.asList()` is from java.util package. The class name is also `Arrays`. So Java is looking for a method called `asList()` from the current class, which does not exist.

Change the class name from `Arrays` to say `PrintArrays`.

Or use this code to explicitly tell to use `java.util.Arrays`.

```
ArrayList<String> header = new ArrayList<>(java.util.Arrays.asList("NAME","REGNUM","ACADEMICYEAR","PROGRAMME","COURSECODE","ASS1","ASS2","ASS3","TEST1","AGGREGATEDMARK","COURSEWORK","GRADE","RESULT"));
```